# How comes `if (Test-Path...)` actually works?

Tags: powershell, syntax

In PowerShell, **syntax for `if`** is as so:

```
if (<test1>)
    {<statement list 1>}
[elseif (<test2>)
    {<statement list 2>}]
[else
    {<statement list 3>}]
```

Another syntax rule is that **for subexpressions, you need to use parentheses** like this:

```
 write-output (get-date)
```

So with these two rules combined, I would expect that the test for some path needs to be written with two sets of parentheses like this:

```
if ((Test-Path ...)) {
    # do something
}
```

However, this also works:

```
if (Test-Path ...) {
    # do something
}
```

and just for the sake of completeness, this **doesn't** work:

```
if (!Test-Path ...) {
    # do something
}
```

(here, you would need to wrap the subexpression in parenthesis as usual).

Can anyone explain the syntax rules that apply here and how comes that I can use the IF test with one parenthesis only? Is it some PowerShell magic or am I misunderstanding the basic syntax rules?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Referring to C.2.2 from [Appendix C: *The PowerShell grammar*](http://www.manning.com/payette/AppCexcerpt.pdf) in Bruce Payette's [Windows PowerShell in Action](http://www.manning.com/payette/), we have:

```
<ifStatementRule> =
  'if' '(' <pipelineRule> ')' <statementBlockRule>
  [ 'elseif' '(' <pipelineRule> ')' <statementBlockRule> ]*
  [ 'else' <statementBlockRule> ]{0|1}
```

This indicates the `(` and `)` tokens as part of the literal syntax for recognizing an `if` statement, and that the `<test>` from the [`about_If`](http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=113234) documentation refers to a pipeline that will be resolved to a Boolean.

Following the pipeline rules, we find:

- `Test-Path ...` parses to a `<cmdletCall>` of `<name> <parameterArgumentToken>`,
- `!Test-Path ...` results in an `<expressionRule>` of `<UnaryOperatorToken> <propertyOrArrayReferenceRule>`, which fails when the cmdlet call cannot match the simple property or array rule, whereas
- `!(Test-Path ...)` is able to match the parenthesized cmdlet call as a sub-expression.

---

**Edit:** See also [PowerShell 2.0 Language Specification](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9706) (thanks to [Roman's answer to another question](https://stackoverflow.com/a/10442985/2495)).

Answer (score 3):

The parentheses after the `if` define a subexpression (if parentheses were required around `Test-Path`, then we would need parens around `$num -eq 5` and every other expression).. The additional parentheses after the not operator is required because `Test-Path` needs to be evaluated before it can be negated. You can try this without an if statement.

This does not work:

```
PS> !Test-Path NonExistent.file
```

This does work:

```
PS> !(Test-Path NonExistent.file)
```

Comment: Try this: `if true`. It will give you a *parser* error. I'm no expert but this seems to me that parentheses are indeed a language construct here, not a subexpression operator.

Comment: @Borek: In PowerShell I think what you'd have to write is 
    if $True