# Is there an official literals / reserved symbol reference for PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

Is there an official (ie. technet or MSDN, not a blog) *reference* for PowerShell literal (or generally reserved) characters/symbols?

Characters I'm referring to include `|` (piping data), `$` (variables), `@()` (arrays), `@{}` (hashtables), and `${}` (I don't even know what this does)

Answer (score 6, accepted):

I would start with `PS C:\> Get-Help About_Reserved_Words` and the continue reading the referenced help pages.

See Also:

- about_Command_Syntax
- about_Escape_Characters
- about_Language_Keywords
- about_Parsing
- about_Quoting_Rules
- about_Script_Blocks
- about_Special_Characters

The built-in help with PowerShell using `Get-Help` is one of the hidden gems.

Comment: [`about_operators`](http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/library/dd347588.aspx) (specifically the "Special Operators" section) also covers a number of (but not all) the operators in question.

Comment: I will have to take a look at that help page. Still ramping up on PS myself

Answer (score 3):

Windows PowerShell Language Specification Version 2.0 can be downloaded from [here](http://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=9706). Almost all the details are there.